# Passing a data frame column in a function: Unknown or uninitialised column

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple function based on ggplot2 to save space.

Example data:

```
X <- rep(c(9:15), each = 9)
ID <- rep(c(2:8), each = 9)
Attitude <- rep(c('A1', 'A2','A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9'), 7)
Answer_a <- rep(1:5, length.out = 63)
time <- as.character(rep(c(0, 1, 3), each = 21))
first_answer <- rep(1:5, length.out = 63)

df <- data.frame(X, ID, Attitude, Answer_a, time, first_answer)
df$time <- as.character(df$time)
```

The code for the function I am trying to create:

```
spaghetti_plot <- function(input, MV, item_level){

  p <- ggplot(na.omit(input[ which(input$MV == item_level), ]), 
     aes( x = time, y = Answer_a, group = ID))
  p <- p + geom_line(aes(colour = first_answer))
  return(p)
}
```

So in essence my question is why I get the warning message `Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column` when I use the function as follows:

spaghett_plot(df, Attitude, 'A1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the function by doing the filtering with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
spaghetti_plot <- function(input, MV, item_level){
 MV <- enquo(MV)
input %>% 
    filter(!!(MV) == item_level) %>% 
    mutate(first_answer = factor(first_answer)) %>%
    ggplot(.,aes( x = time, y = Answer_a, group = ID)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = first_answer))
  }

spaghetti_plot(df, Attitude, 'A1')
```

---

If we need to do this in `base R` i.e. without using any other package except `ggplot`

```
spaghetti_plot <- function(input, MV, item_level){
 MV <- deparse(substitute(MV))
 inputsub <- transform(subset(input, input[[MV]] == item_level), 
                    first_answer = factor(first_answer))
 ggplot(inputsub,aes( x = time, y = Answer_a, group = ID)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = first_answer))
  }

spaghetti_plot(df, Attitude, 'A1')
```

Comment: First, thanks for the solution. It works perfectly. I was wondering however if you also knew a way without the use of a package, or otherwise: why I get this warning message in particular. As far as I know the message occurs if a dataframe column doesn't exist, while in this case it certainly does :)

Comment: @Anonymous  Did you meant without `ggplot` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant without `dplyr` but with `ggplot`